# How to crop and resize the section of an Image within a Rect bounding box?

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow-lite, android-camerax, google-mlkit

After detecting a face with CameraX and MLKit I need to pass the image to a custom TFLite model (I'm using [this one](https://github.com/estebanuri/facemaskdetector/blob/master/android/app/src/main/assets/mask_detector.tflite)), which detects a facemask. The model accepts images of 224x224 pixels, so I need to take out the part of `ImageProxy#getImage()` corresponding to `Face#getBoundingBox()` and resize it accordingly.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17733530/9212745) which could have been fine but `ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail()` can't work with a `Rect` of 4 coordinates and it's relative to the center of the image, while the face's bounding box might be elsewhere.

The TFLite model accepts inputs like this:

```
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer
    .createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
    .loadBuffer(/* the resized image as ByteBuffer */)
```

Note that the `ByteBuffer` will have a size of `224 * 224 * 3 * 4` bytes (where 4 is `DataType.FLOAT32.byteSize()`).

---

**Edit:** I've cleaned up some of the old text because it was getting overwhelming. The [code suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66069562/9212745) actually works: I just forgot to delete a piece of my own code which was already converting the same `ImageProxy` to `Bitmap` and it must have caused some internal buffer to be read until the end, so it was either necessary to rewind it manually or to delete that useless code altogether.

However, even if the `cropRect` is applied to the `ImageProxy` and the underlying `Image`, the resulting bitmap is still full size so there must be something else to do. The model is still returning `NaN` values, so I'm going to experiment with the raw output for a while.

```
fun hasMask(imageProxy: ImageProxy, boundingBox: Rect): Boolean {
    val model = MaskDetector.newInstance(context)
    val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)

    // now the cropRect is set correctly but the image itself isn't
    // cropped before being converted to Bitmap
    imageProxy.setCropRect(box)
    imageProxy.image?.cropRect = box

    val bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmap(imageProxy) ?: return false
    val resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, false)

    // input for the model
    val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(224 * 224 * 3 * DataType.FLOAT32.byteSize())
    resized.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer)

    // use the model and get the result as 2 Floats
    val outputFeature0 = model.process(inputFeature0).outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
    val maskProbability = outputFeature0.floatArray[0]
    val noMaskProbability = outputFeature0.floatArray[1]

    model.close()
    return maskProbability > noMaskProbability
}
```

Comment: Hi, you can look at my solution that I gave here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67348548/13300615. It should help you to get cropped image without converting it to bitmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will provide a better way to handle the image processing when working with ML Kit.

For now, you could try this method: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/BitmapUtils.java#L74

It will convert the ImageProxy to Bitmap, and rotate it to upright. The bounding box from the face detection should be applied to the bitmap directly, which means you should be able to crop the bitmap with the Rect bounding box.

Comment: Thanks, I can't wait for CameraX's future improvements. By saying that "the bounding box should be applied to the bitmap directly", you mean that after calling `detector.process()` with an `InputImage.fromBitmap()` I will have to do `imageProxy.cropRect = boundingBox` and convert `imageProxy` again into a bitmap? I'm sure I'm not getting something because it seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: After fixing some stuff your suggested code finally worked, however the image is still not cropped. I've updated the question with the recent changes.

Comment: `imageProxy.setCropRect(box)` would not crop the image for you. After resizing your image, you could use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int) this method to crop the image with the detected boundingbox.

Comment: Yes, I had already found out that the best (and probably the only) thing to do was to create a new bitmap from a subarea of the other one, like `val cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, boundingBox.left, boundingBox.top, boundingBox.width(), boundingBox.height())`.