# Limit detection area of MLKIT of barcode scanner

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner, google-vision, google-mlkit

I am implementing a barcode scanner using MLKIT in my application (Kotlin). I need the barcode to be processed only when it is visible in a transparent rectangle in the center of the screen. as we see in the picture below.

[PIC 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GwzX.jpg)

Right now my App detects every barcode visible in the camera view as shown below. Is it possible to limit the detection area so the detection only reads from a rectangle in the middle of the screen?

Besides I would like to create a custom PreviewView for a barcode with cameraX, as shown in PIC 1. Thank you.

[PIC 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8T8M.jpg)

Comment: Try making two preview areas that show the same data but on different size. Then, only accept results from the small one :)

Comment: Checkout my article exactly on. For future reference that https://medium.com/@saiful103a/scan-barcode-only-when-they-are-inside-a-specific-area-of-the-preview-android-fcf8e02404d7

Comment: Could you do this? I should do same thing.

Answer (score 0):

ML Kit doesn't support specifying interested area currently, so you have to either crop the preview image or filter out barcode results that not in the specified area. Similar question [How do I make the camera focus only inside the rectangle and read the text inside the rectangle only in a flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68261461/how-do-i-make-the-camera-focus-only-inside-the-rectangle-and-read-the-text-insid/69185514#69185514)